# Rmongodb using regex does not work as expected

Tags: regex, r, mongodb, rmongodb

I am facing an issue while querying mongodb from R(using rmongodb package) using regular expressions. Below is my code:

```
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
regex <- mongo.regex.create("air filter*$", options="i")
mongo.bson.buffer.append.regex(buf, "keyword", regex)
query <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
res <- mongo.find.all(mongo,collection,query)
```

But I get empty result in 'res' from the DB. However, when I check the regex in the DB directly, it gives me valid results. When I give the keyword name without regular expressions in the above query `(eg: "air filter")`,it works fine.

I have tried all possible combinations but in vain.

Following are the example docoments

```
[  
   {  
      "_id":ObjectId("55dcdc72473fdf86c0020d96"),
      "_class":"",
      "keyword":"air filter",
      "synonyms":[  

      ]
   },
   {  
      "_id":ObjectId("55dcdc72473fdf86c0020e0f"),
      "_class":"",
      "keyword":"cabin air filter",
      "synonyms":[  

      ]
   },
   {  
      "_id":ObjectId("55dcdc79473fdf86c002143b"),
      "_class":"",
      "keyword":"secondary air filter",
      "synonyms":[  

      ]
   }
]
```

Note: I have tried json string but cannot use since I need to pass variable as input regex,i.e. I create the regex using `paste0(component[1], "*$")` where component list contains the terms like air filter,etc.

Could you kindly provide some guidance?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some example documents?

Comment: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rmongodb/docs/mongo.regex

Comment: I am asking for the documents from your collection.

Comment: Sorry! My keyword field of the collection contains terms like air filter, cabin air filter, secondary air filter, etc. There are multiple matches for the query.

Comment: { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55dcdc72473fdf86c0020d96"), 
    "_class" : "", 
    "keyword" : "air filter", 
    "synonyms" : [

    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55dcdc72473fdf86c0020e0f"), 
    "_class" : "", 
    "keyword" : "cabin air filter", 
    "synonyms" : [

    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55dcdc79473fdf86c002143b"), 
    "_class" : "", 
    "keyword" : "secondary air filter", 
    "synonyms" : [

    ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I tried and it is working

```
library(rmongodb)
mongo <- mongo.create(host = "localhost", db = "test")

components <- list("air filter", "engine oil")

for (component in components) {
    jsonStr <- paste0('{"keyword" : {"$regex" : "', component, '$"}}')
    mongo.bson.from.JSON(jsonStr)
    res <- mongo.find.all(mongo, "test.coll", mongo.bson.from.JSON(jsonStr))
    print(res)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I rejected the use of json since I need to pass the regex as variable in a list. Eg: I think we cannot do {"$regex": paste0(component[1], "*$")}  for jsonStr. Could you please confirm this?

Comment: Can you please mention your inputs more specifically? Because we do not know what is `component`.

Comment: The component list contains terms like air filter which I need to pass applying regex

Comment: Please edit your question and mention all the inputs.

Comment: Please provide the list values of `components` like components <- list ('a', 'b')

Comment: Could you elaborate please? My component list is as follows: components<-list("air filter", "engine oil", etc)

Comment: I have edited the answer according to `components`. Hope this helps.